# fetchxml does not reuturn column in dynamics

Tags: python, http, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I am using Python to send a http GET request to extract the contacts associated with a segment. The segment for example called "Test Segment" which has a unique identifier "a1-b2-c3".

Below is a fetchXML query I am using:

```
<fetch mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0" page="1" count="5000" paging-cookie=""> 
  <entity name="contact"> 
  <attribute name="fullname"/> 
  <attribute name="contactid"/> 
  <attribute name="emailaddress1"/> 
  <attribute name = "btp_contacttypeid"/>
  <order attribute="fullname" descending="false"/> 
  <link-entity name="msdyncrm_segment" from="msdyncrm_segmentid" to="msdyncrm_segmentmemberid" alias="bb"> 
  <attribute name="msdyncrm_segmentname" />
  <filter type="and"> 
  <condition attribute="msdyncrm_segmentid" operator="eq" uitype="msdyncrm_segment" value="a1-b2-c3"/>
  </filter>
  </link-entity>
  </entity>
  </fetch>
```

I get the following output:

| _odata_etag | fullname | contactid | emailaddress1 | btp_contacttypeid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| W/"83" | Adam Jame | xxxxx | adam@test.com | 742e3888 |

I believe fetchXML automatically removes the null values columns. Technically it is not null but not sure why it returns null
Expected Output:

| _odata_etag | fullname | contactid | emailaddress1 | btp_contacttypeid | msdyncrm_segmentname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| W/"83" | Adam Jame | xxxxx | adam@test.com | 742e3888 | Test Segment |

Can you please help with the following problem?

Comment: uhm, you don't get it under bb.msdyncrm_segmentname?
you are using an odata query with the fetchxml parameter, correct?
also, did you test your fetchxml query with a tool like FetchXML Builder?

Comment: I followed the tutorial from this link - https://passion4dynamics.com/tag/get-contacts-associated-to-a-segment-in-dynamics-365/. The fetchxml query is working but just not returning the msdyncrm_segmentname. Even in  FetchXML Builder it returns the same as Python without the msdyncrm_segmentname

Comment: then the fetchxml query is not correct, are you sure of that column name? sorry but without accessing your instance is difficult to give suggestions

Comment: yes, I am using the correct column name. I built the query from scratch in fetchXML builder with using the UI. That is the correct name. In fetchXML Builder when I click the column show in view then it shows in the output but it is all blank. However, that column has to have the segment name

Comment: I know it's not a solution to your specific issue, but if you are trying to get the name of the segment, if you add the column msdyncrm_segmentid it should return also a column called msdyncrm_segmentidname containing the name (because the field is a lookup) not sure with a fetchxml query but possible with a direct odata query with formatted values on

Comment: I did try that but that did gives the same output. It doesn't even return the msdyncrm_segmentid value

Comment: my best guess is that is something wrong elsewhere, but without access to the system can't test, very strange that you don't get the name of the lookup field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs in two diffrent scenario

1. Permissions to field
2. Null Value

When you execute query over dynamics crm sdk, attribute with null value does not exist in entity. Same problem occurs when user does not have a permission to field.